# How do I split a paragraph into sentences

Tags: java

We are in the process of splitting a paragraph into sentences based on the dot.

```
String[] sentences = message.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s*");
```

The following sentence

```
HP E2B16UT Mini-tower Workstation - 1 x Intel Xeon E3-1245V3 3.40 GHz
```

is broken into

```
HP E2B16UT Mini-tower Workstation - 1 x Intel Xeon E3-1245V3 3
40 GHz
```

How should I avoid splitting on something like 3.40 GHz since we know it forms a word and its not a separator

Comment: @Christian +1, space or newline.

Comment: `\b` word boundary, perhaps?

Comment: You could check for a space after the `.`

Comment: Regex isn't suited for NLP. How would you handle something like `Mr. Smith`?

Comment: @Blender Check that the word just before the split is not Mr. Mrs. or another abbreviation?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String message = "HP E2B16UT Mini-tower Workstation - 1 x Intel Xeon E3-1245V3 3.40 GHz. Hello, you are welcome. StackOverflow. some_email@hotmail.com";
    String[] sentences = message.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s* ");
    for (String s : sentences) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
HP E2B16UT Mini-tower Workstation - 1 x Intel Xeon E3-1245V3 3.40 GHz.
Hello World.
StackOverflow.
some_email@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String message= "This is an example. This string is for split on '.'."//add a space after . for new sentence
```

Replace

```
 String[] sentences = message.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s*");
```

By

```
String[] sentences = message.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s* ");//add a space to split on new sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

try this worked for me easy to understand

```
        String str = "This is how I tried to split a paragraph into a sentence. But, there is a problem. My paragraph includes dates like Jan 13, 2014 , words like U.S and numbers like 2.2. They all got splitted by the above code.";
    String[] sentenceHolder = str.split("[.?!][^A-Z0-9]");
    for (int i = 0; i < sentenceHolder.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(sentenceHolder[i]);
    }
```